# Assigning variables to an array in constructor

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to do the following but it give me error at Mat referenceVectors[11]. Why ?

```
Error   3   error C2536: 'superpixels::superpixels::referenceVectors' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays  c:\users\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\3d_reconstruction\3d_reconstruction\superpixels.h    80  1   3D_Reconstruction
```

I have tried putting it in constructor (not shown here) but I still get an error (a different error).

```
class superpixels {

public:


private:

// Major vectors
Mat Lwall = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 1, 0, 0);
Mat Rwall = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -1, 0, 0);
Mat Floor = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0, -1, 0);
Mat Depth = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0, 0, -1);

// Intermediary vectors
Mat Lwall_Depth = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0.707, 0, -0.707);
Mat Lwall_Floor = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0.707, -0.707, 0);
Mat Floor_Depth = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0, -0.707, -0.707);

Mat Rwall_Depth = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -0.707, 0, -0.707);
Mat Rwall_Floor = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -0.707, 0, -0.707);

Mat Lwall_Depth_Floor = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0.5774, -0.5774, -0.5774);
Mat Rwall_Depth_Floor = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -0.5774, -0.5774, -0.5774);

// All vectors
Mat referenceVectors[11] = { Lwall, Rwall, Floor, Depth, Lwall_Depth, Lwall_Floor, Floor_Depth, Rwall_Depth, Rwall_Floor, Lwall_Depth_Floor, Rwall_Depth_Floor };
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't help you without one.

Comment: it is just a class. there is no working example

Comment: That's not all. What's the error message? For example

Comment: @FirstStep in `C++11` you can assign data-members during definition right inside class in any section (public/private/protected).

Comment: @user1034749 but this is c++ and not c++11.

Comment: @FirstStep technically c++11 also c++.

Comment: Hi thanks ! I have edited to include the error and it says "cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays"

Comment: [Why do I seem to recall seeing this code before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182381/initialize-array-with-const-variables-inside-class)

Comment: @WhozCraig lol good catch

Comment: @FirstStep C++ is currently C++14, which is largely C++11 compatible.

Comment: Why is the title "Assigning variables to an array in constructor"? Where is the constructor?
Also, which VS version are you using?

Comment: also, which version of C++ is this? (not sure how others got to understand this is > C++11)

Comment: @user1034749 turned out that you are right